# Is there an Algorithm for this recursive problem fetching data from an api?

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

I am working on fetching some data from a server, and there are 6 endpoints I need to hit and fetch data from. but the problem I can't get my head around writing an efficient algorithm without tons of for `loops` and `ifs`. I tried t divide the problem into smaller chunks but I can't come up with a solution.

```
async function fetch_children(endpoint, state) {
  const temp = await call_api(endpoint, state);
  state["children"] = await temp;
  state["endpoint"] = endpoint;
  return state;
}

async function loop_over(state) {
  const item = await fetch_children(endpoints[0], state);
  if (item["children"]) {
    for (const idx in item["children"]) {
      item["children"][idx] = await fetch_children(
        endpoints[1],
        item["children"][idx]
      );

      if (item["children"][idx]["children"]) {
        for (const idm in item["children"][idx]["children"]) {
          item["children"][idx]["children"][idm] = await fetch_children(
            endpoints[2],
            item["children"][idx]["children"][idm]
          );
          if (item["children"][idx]["children"][idm]["children"]) {
            for (const id in item["children"][idx]["children"][idm][
              "children"
            ]) {
              item["children"][idx]["children"][idm]["children"][id] =
                await fetch_children(
                  endpoints[3],
                  item["children"][idx]["children"][idm]["children"][id]
                );
              if (
                item["children"][idx]["children"][idm]["children"][id][
                  "children"
                ]
              ) {
                for (const idd in item["children"][idx]["children"][idm][
                  "children"
                ][id]["children"]) {
                  item["children"][idx]["children"][idm]["children"][id][
                    "children"
                  ][idd] = await fetch_children(
                    endpoints[5],
                    item["children"][idx]["children"][idm]["children"][id][
                      "children"
                    ][idd]
                  );
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return item;
}
```

one of my attempts:

```
async function fetch_children(endpoint, state) {
  const temp = await call_api(endpoint, state);
  state["children"] = await temp;
  state["endpoint"] = endpoint;
  return state;
}

async function loop_over(endpoint, place) {
  const item = await fetch_children(endpoint, place);
  return item;
}

async function test(endpoints, state) {
  state = await loop_over(endpoints.pop(), state);
  if (state["children"].length >= 1 || endpoints.length >= 1) {
    for (const idx in state["children"]) {
      state["children"][idx] = await test(endpoints, state["children"][idx]);
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

but it didn't work because for some reason endpoints is out of element even though I am checking the length

any help is appreciated, what an algorithm or what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

for more context the response tree need to looks like the following:

```
/// response of loop and ifs aforementioned function
{
  "name": "",
  "id": "",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "id": "",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "id": "",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "",
              "id": "",
              "children": [
                { "name": "", "id": "" },
                { "name": "", "id": "" },
                { "name": "", "id": "" },
                { "name": "", "id": "" },
                { "name": "", "id": "" },
                { "name": "", "id": "" },
              ],
              "endpoint": "endpoints[3]"
            }
          ],
          "endpoint": "endpoints[2]"
        }
      ],
      "endpoint": "endpoints[1]"
    },
    {
        ....
    },
     ...
]
```

```
async function fetch_children(endpoint, state) {
  const temp = await call_api(endpoint, state);
  state["children"] = await temp;
  state["endpoint"] = endpoint;
  return state;
}

async function loop_over(endpoint, place) {
  const item = await fetch_children(endpoint, place);
  return item;
}

async function test(endpoints, state) {
  state = await loop_over(endpoints.pop(), state);
  if (state["children"].length >= 1 || endpoints.length >= 1) {
    for (const idx in state["children"]) {
      state["children"][idx] = await test(endpoints, state["children"][idx]);
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: At a quick glance, `endpoints.pop()` will modify `endpoints` in-place, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @AKX, I tried to pass endpoints.slice(1) and then call loop_over(endpoints[0], state) but still the problem

Comment: Is the `call_api` affected by the contents of `state` ?  and if so, how ? can you post the relevant code ?

Comment: Can you explain in the question why you need to **pass** the state to `call_api` when you actually want the state to be **returned**? Can you add what the initiating call would be of the whole process?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you'll have a better time working "inside out":

```
async function fetchFromEndpoint(endpoint) {
  // TODO: replace with actual fetcher
  return {
    name: `name of ${endpoint}`,
    id: `id of ${endpoint}`,
    children: [],
  };
}

async function recurse(endpoints) {
  const endpoint = endpoints.shift();
  const response = await fetchFromEndpoint(endpoint);
  response.endpoint = endpoint;
  if (endpoints.length > 0) {
    response.children = [await recurse(endpoints)];
  }
  return response;
}

recurse(["end1", "end2", "end3"]).then(console.log);
```

This prints out

```
{
  name: 'name of end1',
  id: 'id of end1',
  children: [
    {
      name: 'name of end2',
      id: 'id of end2',
      children: [Array],
      endpoint: 'end2'
    }
  ],
  endpoint: 'end1'
}
```

(and you can imagine the inner `Array` contains an end3 object)

Note that the `endpoints` array passed to `recurse` will be mutated by it.